# LookupDispatchAction problem

Tags: java, spring, struts

I have a problem regarding the LookupDispatchAction class.

The following error i am getting while working,

The error is:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   ServletException in
>   '/admin/custom-report.html?action=searchAttributes': You must specify the value attribute
>   or nested tag content
>
> Click to view the complete technical
>   details of this problem:
>
> ServletException in
>   '/admin/custom-report.html?action=searchAttributes': You must specify the value attribute
>   or nested tag content
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
>   ServletException in
>   '/admin/custom-report.html?action=searchAttributes': You must specify the value attribute
>   or nested tag content at
>   org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:924)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:462)
>   at
>   _jsp._layout._providerLayout._jspService(_providerLayout.java:218)
>   at
>   com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:60)
>   at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:416)
>   at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:478)
>   at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:401)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>   at

and My code is

.jsp file (based on radio button selection the request forwarded to aciton class):

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<bean:message key="custom.report.go" />" id="act" />
```

my action class:

```
public class CustomReportAction extends LookupDispatchAction {

  protected Map getKeyMethodMap() 
  {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("custom.report.home", "home");
    map.put("custom.report.searchattributes", "searchAttributes");
    map.put("custom.report.go", "search");
    return map;
  }

  public ActionForward searchAttributes(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
  {
-----
---
}
```

struts-config :

```
<action path="/admin/custom-report" type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" name="CustomReportBean" parameter="action" scope="request" validate="false"> 
      <forward name="searchattributes" path="/jsp/report/customReportSearch.jsp"/>
      <forward name="search" path="customReport"/>
    </action>
```

please help me here

thanks in advance.

Comment: you know how to format code, right?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason of your error is a wrong syntax

You open double quotes before `<bean:message` and close it after `key=`. 
For using nested quotes you have to escape it or use a single one for a nested expression.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<bean:message key=\"custom.report.go\" />" id="act" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<bean:message key='custom.report.go' />" id="act" />
```